# Check if database matches and create user using PG/PLSQL

Tags: postgresql

The below script runs but does not create the user when database name matches?
i just cannot spot what i am doing wrong here.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
lc_s_db_name CONSTANT VARCHAR(30) := 'dev';
lv_db_name  VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
    select datname into lv_db_name from pg_catalog.pg_database;
     
    IF lv_db_name in (lc_s_db_name )
    THEN
        create role monitor LOGIN PASSWORD 'monitor';
    END IF;
 END
 $do$;
```

Comment: Add `RAISE NOTICE 'lv_db_name = %', lv_db_name;` and see what you get? In my case a single name `template0`. You are trying to `select into` a `varchar` variable a record set. That is not going to work.  Either loop over the query or use from here [Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) the function `string_agg()`.

Comment: Sorry, how do I loop over a query ? Sorry new to this

Comment: The docs are your friend [plpgsl query loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING). If you are new you should go through this [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) a couple of times. It will answer most of your questions.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "*when database name matches*"? Which database's name, the one you're currently connected to?

Comment: We put this code in a common baseline script that runs on multiple envs. Users deploy this on local docker too so all I want is this script to run on our stg and prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select query picks *one* database name of the list of all databases. That's not necessarily the one you are connected to.

To get the name of the database you are connected to, use the function `current_database()`

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  lc_s_db_names CONSTANT text[] := array['dev', 'dev2'];
BEGIN
  IF current_database() = any(lc_s_db_names)
  THEN
    create role monitor LOGIN PASSWORD 'monitor';
  END IF;
END
$do$;
```

Comment: This is so helpful. Really appreciate it. I have a other question that if I want this to run on multiple databases from an automation perspective ?

Comment: Would it simply be defining multiple variables with database name and having current_database in (lc_s_db_name, n, n)?

Comment: @nick: use an array of names. See my eedit

Comment: thank you so much sir! This has helped me greatly